# How to update the schedule fields and data set dynamically

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion

We need to update the fields and data set dynamically on user interaction.
I tried to do it by setting the react state but it doesn't work: the fields set seems not updating and i couldn't find how to do it in the documentation neither.
this is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gw8qs1-6tts6v) reproducing it.

Cheers.

Comment: You should not be mutating the state. Also, I don't use syncfusion but I tested to see if EndTime2 would work from initialization and it doesn't. You can change EndTime's value in your handler and it will update the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

We have validated your reported scenario in the shared sample. In that, you are missed to add an index for the fields(highlighted in below code). So the field is not updated properly. Kindly refer the below for more details.

```
fields: state.fields[0]
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gw8qs1-xwukd6?file=index.js
UG: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/appointments/#event-fields